# Angular routing based on regex

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I've run into an issue with Angular (5.x) routing and I'm out of ideas of how to fix it.

I have a module which is dedicated to work with CRUD operations for some type of entities. At this moment I have the following router config:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'vacancies', canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], component: VacanciesContainer,
    children: [
        { path: '', component: VacanciesComponent },
        { path: 'create', component: VacancyCreateComponent },
        { path: 'archived', children: [
            { path: '', component: ArchivedVacanciesComponent },
            { matcher: GuidMatcher, component: VacancyCardComponent }
        ]},
        { matcher: GuidMatcher,  children: [
            { path: '', component: VacancyCardComponent },
            { path: 'edit', redirectTo: 'http://google.com' }
        ]}
    ]
}];
```

GuidMatcher is some method which returns UrlMatchResult if substring is a valid GUID.
According to this '/vacancies/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' will navigate to the details page. However '/vacancies/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/edit' will not redirect to http://google.com. Angular router will do nothing for this route.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `export function GuidMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]): UrlMatchResult {
    if (url.length === 0) {
        return null;
    }

    const reg = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}(-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}){3}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{12}$/;
    const param = url[0].toString();

    if (param.match(reg)) {
        return ({ consumed: url, posParams: { id: url[0] } });
    }

    return null;
}`

here is GuidMatcher code.

Comment: I'm not sure router is supposed to work with external routes.

Comment: it doesn't work even if I use `component: VacancyEditComponent` instead of redirectTo.

Comment: `{ path: ':id/edit', component: VacancyEditComponent },
            { matcher: GuidMatcher, component: VacancyCardComponent }` this works fine and it could be possibly the only solution for this issue ?